# Vertical Alignment in Proof Tree

Tags: logic, proof-package, bussproofs, logicproof

I have tried a few packages to align inference rules but I have not figured out how to avoid the following problem. My proof tree looks like this:

```
           A
-------------------------  
  B                
-----  
  D                 C
```

but should look like this:

```
           A
-------------------------  
  B                C  
-----  
  D
```

Do you have any advice for a package that supports that alignment? Specifically can I use \infer for this somehow? I tried to include a minimum working example but when I minimize the proof tree is not even working for the above anymore and I don't seem to be able to figure out why. I also tried bussproofs unsuccessfully.

Comment: Welcome! In the future, please always include a small example i.e. code. For example, you could have included your attempt to use `bussproofs`. That gives people a starting point, even if it doesn't work. Also, please say what doesn't work. Do you get an error? Which? Does it compile but give the wrong output? What's wrong? Etc.

Comment: Where is `\infer` from? I'm not sure if you mean the `\infer1` etc. from `ebproof` or something else?

Comment: Thanks you both. Sorry, about the missing example. I made a bunch of changes and suddenly even the tree above (that I managed to generate with different packages) would not work anymore and I did not know how to get it back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the kind of proof you're drawing, you need to tell `bussproofs` to turn the tree upside down. This can be done with the `\rootAtTop` command. If all of your proofs look like this, then you can set the root globally using the command `\alwaysRootAtTop` in the preamble, in which case you don't need to specify it for each proof.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bussproofs}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
\rootAtTop
  \AxiomC{D}
  \UnaryInfC{B}
  \AxiomC{C}
  \BinaryInfC{A}      
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Answer (score 1):

A more recent alternative to `bussproofs` is `ebproof`. This was basically written to overcome certain limitations in `bussproofs` and because its author didn't like all of the decisions implemented in `bussproofs`'s design.

Example using `ebproof` for an inline and a displayed proof:

[image: ebproof inline and display]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ebproof}
\begin{document}
\begin{prooftree}
  [proof style=downwards]
  \hypo{D}
  \infer1{B}
  \hypo{C}
  \infer2{A}
\end{prooftree}
\begin{prooftree}*
  [proof style=downwards]
  \hypo{D}
  \infer1{B}
  \hypo{C}
  \infer2{A}
\end{prooftree}
\end{document}
```

However, I recommend defining semantic markup for the symbols you need and avoiding the direct use of names such as `\vdash` found in `ebproof`'s manual. Alternatively, use the `turnstile` package.